# How can i find the user id / email for this youtube channel

Tags: youtube-api

Can any one help me to find the user id / email for this Youtube Channel.
I don't have any programming background.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGS6tPWTNYLy04JSFUrT7ew

Answer (score 0):

No you won't be able to in new API v3 documentation explains

> The biggest takeaway for developers using the older Data API v2 is
>   that you must be aware that not every YouTube channel has a unique
>   username. Fortunately, every YouTube channel is guaranteed to have a
>   unique channel ID associated with it, represented by the value in the
>    tag, and that’s the value that we recommend developers
>   use instead of usernames. For instance, if you have a database that
>   maps YouTube usernames to information about that channel, your older
>   entries should continue to work. (Existing channels won’t lose their
>   usernames.) However, as time goes on, it will become more and more
>   likely that you’ll have to work with channels that can’t be uniquely
>   identified by a username.

Answer (score 0):

A channel doesn't have an email address associated to it you can see that by checking the [Channel resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource).   If you are authenticated with a user and you can use the token info end point to get info about the user

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123

You can also go though the people api

> https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

For both those calls you must be authenticated.   You cant get email for a user who you dont have access to